# Keeping a listBox's selectedIndex updated while navigating with keyboard

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
     {
          item = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
     }
}
```

Then in the Load event of the Form where the listBox1 is on in the designer I did:

```
private void NewForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Size = new Size(416, 506);
     this.Location = new Point(23, 258);
     listBoxIndexs();
     this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

listBoxIndexs() is:

```
private void listBoxIndexs()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < Form1.test.Count; i++)
     {
          listBox1.Items.Add(Form1.test[i]);
     }
}
```

In the Load event, I did:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

So when I make Show to this Form i see the listBox when index 0 is already selected.
The problem is when im using my keys arrows up and down to move between the items i see only the Frame around the items moving up down the selectedIndex is all the time keep on 0.

How can i fix it?

I tried to add after the  `this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;` also `listBox1.Select();` but it didn't help.

I'm using visual studio c# 2010 pro .net 4 Client Profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your `ListBox.SelectionMode` is set to `One`.

If it is set to `MultiSimple` or `MultiExtended`, selections will only occur when the user uses the spacebar or the mouse button to select the item. The arrow keys in these modes just moves the selection marquee.